# How to remove all li element of same class except first li element in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple li tags inside ul. Here I need to remove all li tag have class 'removeMe' except first li having 'removeMe' class.Here these tags can be n number may be 2 or 3 or 4 etc.'This is the first div
This is the first div'.I can able to remove only 2nd li of 'removeMe' class.Here is the code below.

### HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<span>Hi</span
<li class="abc212">This is the first div</li>
<li class="abc333">This is the first div</li>
<li class="removeMe">This is the first div</li>
<li class="removeMe">This is the SECOND div, should not show</li>
<li class="removeMe">This is the third div</li>
</ul>
```

### script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('li:nth-child(4).removeMe').hide();
});
```

Comment: i'd suggest removing that span from the UL, it's invalid, and how the browser deals with that may differ from browser to browser, thus causing some of the below solutions to fail in some browsers but not others.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to use remove() for remove any element . Try to use this :

```
$('.removeMe').each(function(index){
   if(index !=1)
       $(this).remove();
});
```

**Hope this will help you**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:gt()`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector

```js
$('li.removeMe:gt(0)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="abc212">This is the first div</li>
  <li class="abc333">This is the first div</li>
  <li class="removeMe">This is the first div</li>
  <li class="removeMe">This is the SECOND div, should not show</li>
  <li class="removeMe">This is the third div</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all the elements with class `removeMe` and iterate over it starting from index 1 and then use `remove()` to remove the element

```js
let getAllRemoveMe = $('.removeMe');

for (let i = 1; i < getAllRemoveMe.length; i++) {
  getAllRemoveMe[i].remove()

}
```

```css
.removeMe {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <li class="abc212">This is the first div</li>
  <li class="abc333">This is the first div</li>
  <li class="removeMe">This is the first div</li>
  <li class="removeMe">This is the SECOND div, should not show</li>
  <li class="removeMe">This is the third div</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using vanilla JS:

```js
var lists = document.querySelectorAll("li.removeMe");

for(var i = 1; i < lists.length; i++) {
  lists[i].parentElement.removeChild(lists[i]);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <li class="abc212">This is the first div</li>
  <li class="abc333">This is the first div</li>
  <li class="removeMe">This is the first div</li>
  <li class="removeMe">This is the SECOND div, should not show</li>
  <li class="removeMe">This is the third div</li>
</ul>
```